# PHP Process 2 forms at once

Tags: php

I would like to know if its possible to process 2 forms at once? my scenario is this:

I have a contact page on my website which consists of:

- 1) Customer Details
- 2a) General Enquiry
- 2b) Get Quote
- 2c) Check Availability

section 1 is always the same is a form on its own, where as section 2 will only show details for one of the options (selectable from drop down box.)

so in total I have 4 forms of which 2 will always be filled in, and i need to process them both to email through to me. I don't want to have to include section 1 at the top of each form if i can help it)

I hope this all makes sense.

Comment: Why not just make it one form?

Comment: Make one form, do the processing with PHP.

Comment: It will have to be one form. Your processing code will use the option that drives the different forms to handle the processing.

Comment: Is http://php.net/include helpful?

Comment: are your all form are at one page and you are rolling over to different forms using `jquery`?

Comment: try working with "fieldset". :-)

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: You can only submit one form at a time.

Comment: No, it can not be done with jquery. jquery is a javascript framework. However.. what you can do with javascript is a) merge several forms into one big form and submit it or b) send multiple forms with asynchronous requests - one after the other.

Comment: well thats what i was talking about jquery (javascripting) is always a solution to such sort of problem. So long story short it cannot be done with php but can be done with little brain storming via javascripting

Comment: YOu didn't get it. You can not send two forms at once. This has nothing to do with PHP at all.

Comment: Well I never said that it has to do with php , I only said it can be done via javascripting

Comment: It has to do with how forms are handled in the HTTP protocol. What you're talking about is changing two forms to one form. But when you want this, there is pretty much no reason to do it with javascript. You can simply print out all form controls as one form in the first place. ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22189/discussion-between-jan-and-soft-genic)

Comment: Well I was talking about storing the values of the forms and using those values by checking whether they are set or not and process the output accordingly. `An idea thats all`.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you dont want to make it one form? Seems like it would be a lot easier to make it one form and do all of the processing on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

You can only submit one form at a time. You have a couple of options:

1) Combine the two forms into one form and use CSS/JavaScript to show/hide the relevant fields. This way, all of the form fields will be submitted (including the ones you're not interested in). This is what I would do.

2) When the user submits the form, use JavaScript to send the appropriate data to the backend.